# How to play MIDI-file to some midi output device?

Tags: windows-7, midi

I have midi file (.mid) and want to specify what output device it will be played to. Now it is  played to some standard Windows midi device ("Microsoft MIDI Mapper" or something like that).

(Windows 7 64-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my previous answer on a related question: [How is media player playing midi .mid files?](https://superuser.com/questions/120986/how-is-media-player-playing-midi-mid-files)

To summarize, Win7 does not have a MIDI mapper anymore so it always uses the default MIDI device.

Comment: Is there any software that can play midi file to not default device?

Comment: Try Googling for Windows 7 MIDI, as I suggested in my other post. There are some half-baked solutions. I don't use MIDI so I don't have any experience with them.

Comment: Is it possible to change the "default MIDI device"?

Answer (score 0):

Re: MIDI to another device.

This may not be a solution that is practical, but check out www.musescore.org

This is a notation program with import and MIDI playback capabilities.
Regards,

Comment: How to make it send midi to my midi output device? I tried to uncheck "Use internal sythesizer", it selected "Use midi output" and after restarting program it doesn't sound.

Comment: I don't have a MIDI input right now so I can't try it. If you ask on the musescore support forum, you will get instructions. The support is very good.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You should use some of the old way midi
Try this http://www.sdim.gr/mpc/
or this http://www.benryves.com/products/vistamidi

Answer (score 0):

[vanBasco's Karaoke Player](http://www.vanbasco.com/karaokeplayer/) can play MIDI files, and you can set it to play MIDI out and set it to be default player for MIDI.

For me, it is very good because I can change pitch, velocity and tempo.

Answer (score 0):

While [VistaMidi](http://www.benryves.com/products/vistamidi) may work in Vista and Windows 7, it has no effect whatsoever in later versions. The only solution that worked for me in Windows 8 and 10 was [CoolSoft MIDI mapper](http://coolsoft.altervista.org/en/forum/thread/427). It installs itself as MIDI device 0 and allows you to configure which device you'd like to pass MIDI commands to.

The download links are "protected" for some very odd reason, try using `guestaccount`/`guestaccount` as login/password.